# How to get newly added or modified files with changed color in project view in PHPStorm

Tags: phpstorm, highlight, last-modified, phpstorm-2017.1

I'm actually trying to get newly added or modified files highlighted (changed color) in project view. I seen this on Atom, WebStorm & PHPStorm,

But I can't see the option in my PHPStorm, Has the latest version (2017.1.2), I checked settings but it seems that I am not aware of how to do that or any relevant option there.

Please consider checking the following screenshot, I actually want that in my PHPStorm. (Note that I changed color scheme & different languages syntax highlighting options heavily)

(Having trouble uploading file here,  so pls visit the link)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hIk8.jpg

Comment: Modified/added files are highlighted automatically if you project uses a version control (for instance, Git). Open Preferences | Version Control to configure it.

Comment: I know that, but I want that without relating to VCS/SCM. Did you seen? Atom has this feature, is there a way to do it in PHPStorm? btw, Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There's no such way then.